# JS File Not Loading When URL is Directory

Tags: javascript, html, http-status-code-404, loading, server

I wrote a simple 404 page for my website that tells you a joke every time it is loaded. I am accomplishing this with the use of the StackExhange API and am drawing questions off of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234075/what-is-your-best-programmer-joke).

Everything works as intended when I purposely trigger the 404 page with a garbage file url. For example when I go to `www.domain.com/garbage`, the 404 page loads as expected. My `404.shtml` has a `script` tag that loads a `404.js` script that I wrote and everything is great.

However, when I attempt to get a 404 page by routing to a garbage *directory* as apposed to a garbage *file*, the script cannot be found. For example, `www.domain.com/garbage/` does **NOT** load the `404.js` script despite the correct `404.shtml` page being loaded.

Here is the `head` section of my HTML file.

```
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
            type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="404.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

**Note**: The external jQuery script is loaded **both** times, but `404.js` is only loaded for the **first** request example.

Here is the console for both requests, the first one is the request for a garbage file and the second is the request for a garbage directory.

**First URL:** www.domain.com/garbage
`// a long JSON response from the StackExhange API that indicates that the script loaded`

**Second URL:** www.domain.com/garbage/
`[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (404.js, line 0)`

**Question** What is causing the `404.js` script to not be loaded when I attempt to access an invalid directory within my site when the same script loads when I attempt to access an invalid file?

**What I Have Tried**

- A plethora of Google searches.

  Triple check that all script tags are pointing to the correct files

Thank you for your time. If you wish to do some more digging, you can see the actual problem in action at `briantracy.xyz/garbage` and `briantracy.xyz/garbage/`.

Comment: You might try putting in the relative path ... `src="/issue/404.js"` (this is probably not the path, but you get the idea.

Comment: please put script tag bottom of the body tag and try.

Comment: missing files probably redirect to root or wherever your 404 file is, whereas folders stay at the relative path and merely show the content of your 404 file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big Thanks to @rfornal for suggesting making a relative file path to the script. Channging the following line in the  `head` section

```
<script src="404.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
             ^^^^^^
```

by prepending the root directory (where `404.js` is located) to the file path does the trick.

```
<script src="/404.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
             ^^^^^^^
```